# Solr and Lucene, including in web application

Tags: mysql, web-applications, solr, lucene

I want to add simple search functionality into an existing **Java** web application.
Search should be done on existing database fields.
It is an web-applicaiton deployed on wildfly, REST-Services and MySql-DB.

After some research, my first impression was, using **Solr** I will get what I want.

BUT: As I'am not allowed to deploy one more application to customers environments, **Solr** doesn't fit any more.

As I understood, there are two ways to fix this:

1. Using EmbeddedSolr
2. "Self-build solr" ([http://javaskeleton.blogspot.de/2011/07/adding-solr-to-existing-web-application.html](http://javaskeleton.blogspot.de/2011/07/adding-solr-to-existing-web-application.html/))

Which way should I go, to implement search to my web-app ?

Or should I switch to **Lucene** ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Unfortunately you seem to ask for opinions on a very broad question. That's 2 reasons why your question does not fit here. You better try to ask precise and clear questions, chop up your problem in different parts if that's necessary.

Comment: I'am not sure if I got you, but this kinde of question is fundamental imho. Depending on this, I have to decide which way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd way seems old and although the post seems to be removed I think I got what the author meant, from the title.

IMO the 1st way is better because you will be using Solr as it should be used, as a black box, without mixing up things with your webapp.

Having said that, keep in mind that the embedded solr isn't a good choice for a production environment because it is a standalone module, mainly not scalable.

I suggest you to write your Solr client code in a decoupled way: your webapp should deal only with SolrServer abstract class. Behind the scenes  you'll instantiate an EmbeddedSolrServer at the moment. Later, if you want to scale your search service, this design will let you to switch to another impl (LBHttpServer, SolrCloud) with a small refactoring effort.

Comment: thank you. When I started to investigate, about adding Search-Engine to my web-app, I was not able to finde some best practice, how to handle my problem, as I'am not allowed to deploy one more application on clients environment, "just for search". I tried to finde a solution to manage it with Solr as it seems to me more handy for beginning.But I doesn't finde a solution for that, as Solr is an out of box web-app, and there is not  "lib/jar-Solution". So I swichted to Lucene.

Comment: Ok, now it's clear. The advantage of and embedded Solr over Lucene relies on those features that Solr adds on top of Lucene (e.g. faceting, more like this and so on). So if you need a library "just for search" Lucene is great.

Answer (score 0):

So I will describe my way that I've chosen.

First of all, yes **Lucene** is my friend.

In my web-app I creaded an `@WebListener`. This will create one Index, and delete it if already exists, at start of my web-app.

The content of the Index are some database-filed values of three Objects, that have to be searched.

In my SearchService(REST) I build up my QuerySearch, and acces this Index.

Additonally I want extend existing REST-Services (not yet done). So when editing objectTypes (CUD) included in Index, the Index have to be update.

Feel free, to give me some suggestions or best practices.